# Find the consecutive positive and negative elements for the entire array using matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a channel from which I take around 1 million samples now it contains both positive and negative values in it. My intention is to find the consecutive positive and negative integers(doesn't have to be same) and once the value is found I can then perform some operations on it. I have given my code below. chA is my channel from where i derive my inputs as values. The code is only giving me a value of 43.2600, which ideally should have given an array of numbers as there are lots of samples which are consecutive positive and negative.

```
consider the array as [0,1,-3,4,5,6,7,8,9,-19]
for i = 1:1000000 % loops strats from 1 and ends at 1000000
if (chA(i)<0) && (chA((i+1) >0)) % if i = 1, i+1 = -3 <it satisfy the condition>
tan = ((chA(i+1))- chA(i)); %calculate it
deltaOfTime = tan/i; %store the value here in the vector deltaOfTime
end
now in the next iteration it should be able to find out the next consecutive positive and negative value which is 9,-19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do...

```
origVec=[0,1,-3,4,5,6,7,8,9,-19];

yTemp=origVec(:); %make a column vector
yTemp = [NaN; yTemp; NaN]; %NaN pad

iTemp = (1:numel(yTemp)).'; %Get index array

% keep only the first of any adjacent pairs of equal values (including NaN).
yFinite = ~isnan(yTemp);
iNeq = [true;((yTemp(1:end-1) ~= yTemp(2:end)) & ...
(yFinite(1:end-1) | yFinite(2:end)))];
iTemp = iTemp(iNeq);

% take the sign of the first sample derivative
s = sign(diff(yTemp(iTemp)));

% find local maxima
iMax = [false;diff(s)<0];
iPk = iTemp(iMax)-1;

pksAndFollowingIdx = [iPk.';iPk.'+1]; %get neighbouring +ve and -ve values
deltaOfTime = diff(origVec(pksAndFollowingIdx))./iPk.'; %take difference between consecutive positive and negative values
```

That is, if your original code was supposed to be something more like:

```
for i = 1:10-1 % loop through array???
    if (origVec(i)>0) && (origVec(i+1) <0) % check neighbouring +ve THEN -ve values???
        tan12 = ((origVec(i+1))- origVec(i)); %calculate difference???
        deltaOfTime(i) = tan12/i % deltaOfTime, not sure how this is "delta of time"???
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save each of the value you calculate rather than overwrite it each loop:

```
deltaOfTime = zeros(1,1000000);
for i = 1:1000000 % loops strats from 1 and ends at 1000000
    if (chA(i)<0) && (chA((i+1) >0)) % if i = 1, i+1 = -3 <it satisfy the condition>
    tan = ((chA(i+1))- chA(i)); %calculate it
    deltaOfTime(i) = tan/i; %store the value here in the vector deltaOfTime
end
```

However there are are better way to calculate the transitions and you would not need to loop through your signal, or pre-allocate large vector `deltaOfTime`.

This is a way to not pre-allocate values, However it might be slower as the array changes within the loop:

```
for i = 1:1000000 % loops strats from 1 and ends at 1000000
    if (chA(i)<0) && (chA((i+1) >0)) % if i = 1, i+1 = -3 <it satisfy the condition>
    tan = ((chA(i+1))- chA(i)); %calculate it
    deltaOfTime = cat(2,deltaOfTime,tan/i); %store the value here in the vector deltaOfTime
end
```

Another try to correct all the bugs in the code:

```
for i = 1:length(chA)-1
    if (chA(i)<0) && (chA((i+1) >0))
        temp = ((chA(i+1))- chA(i));
        deltaOfTime = cat(2,deltaOfTime,temp/i);
    end
end
```

Fixed the if-statement, as well a the looping condition which will give you an error if you array is exactly 1million long.

---

Note: avoid using variable names of existing function e.g. `tan`.

Note2: Are you sure that you do not want both the definition of `tan` and `deltaOfTime` to be inside the `if`-statement?

Comment: thanks thats looks preety helpful. But i dont want to store the values which are coming as zero rest i will store. Is it possible?

Comment: thanks thats looks pretty helpful. But i dont want to store the values which are coming as zero or null rest i will store. as i need to plot those result of deltaOfTime on the figure. Is it possible?

Comment: consider the array as [0,1,-3,4,5,6,7,8,9,-19]
for i = 1:1000000 % loops strats from 1 and ends at 1000000
if (chA(i)<0) && (chA((i+1) >0)) % if i = 1, i+1 = -3 <it satisfy the condition>
tan = ((chA(i+1))- chA(i)); %calculate it
deltaOfTime = tan/i; %store the value here in the vector deltaOfTime
end
now in the next iteration it should be able to find out the next consecutive positive and negative value which is 9,-19

Comment: @jayantadeb If this answers you question consider accepting it. Otherwise please provide feedback if something is missing